# How to put EditText into TextView

Tags: android

I have a sentence, user has to put his data into sentence (one word).

I tried to use for it LinearLayout with TextView (beginning of the sentence), EditText with ems=5(here user should put his data), then TextView(end of the sentence) (See the code below). But in this realization it doesn't look appropriate, when we use long sentence and it moves part of it to the next line.

On emulator it looks like:

```
|Blablabla ________ blablabla|    
|                   blabla.  |
```

It puts the end of the sentence under the second TextView. But I need that the second line starts from the beginning of new line, like:

```
|Blablabla ________ blablabla|    
|blabla.                     |
```

I tried to use the solution from Git-Hub: [flow-text](https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView) but got that kind of result:
[image]

**How can I solve this problem? Thanks for watching this post!**

XML:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="@string/firstPart_1"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:paddingBottom="6dp"
            android:ems="7"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="@string/firstPart_2"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

XML (flow-text):

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <uk.co.deanwild.flowtextview.FlowTextView
        android:id="@+id/ftv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="блабла"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"
            android:ems="5"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </uk.co.deanwild.flowtextview.FlowTextView>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Either the textviews will wrap or be truncated for long strings if you force them to a single line.... I can't see a way around that

Comment: Why you are not having the complete textview and on clicking on the textview opening a dialog or popup to enter the text?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use the linear layout (horizontal) for a single line.

```
     <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="fill in the blanks:" />
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal">
      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Your name is: "/>
      <EditText
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="5"/>
  </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:text="Hello Brother, how are you"  />
</LinearLayout>
```

It is working as you want. :)

Comment: This time I have provided the complete code... which worked as you want to do.

Comment: Sorry, but it complitly doesn't work how I want. I need to put TextView in one line with EditText, after it, if TextView too long moves it in the beginning of the second line.

Comment: you need to put only that number of words in the horizontal linear layout(we are using it for only a single line which is having edit text )such that it doesn't jump to the second line. Remaining words you can put after the horizontal linear layout.

Answer (score 0):

Since your text is going to be of rich format as shown in the picture, you can consider using a `WebView`.

In this case, you can arrange your elements using HTML and use rich texts using CSS styling.

Also you can use WebView mechanisms provided for communication between Java side and JavaScript side, in order to make a bridge from that text box to your Java logics. ([Example](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-bind-javascript-code-to-android-code/))